# Onomatopoeia in Italian

Tags: translation, sound

What's the Italian equivalent for words such as, "**crash**", "**bang**", "**snap**", "**woosh**", "**wallop**" etc? Are there any onomatopoeia references out there that consolidate these equivalents in Italian?

Comment: If you refer only to the words that can be found in comic books, I think they are more or less the same. See [https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossario_dei_fumetti](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossario_dei_fumetti). Then there are some italianized words, e.g. "bum" for "boom".

Comment: @santos welcome on Italian SE!

Comment: Is “wallop” actually an onomatopoeia? My dictionary gives its as “from Old Northern French walop (noun), waloper (verb), perhaps from a Germanic phrase meaning ‘run well’, from the bases of well and leap”.

Comment: For wallop I found a likeness with the Italian term patapum

Comment: @abarisone, yes, but I just questioned the English word “wallop” being an actual onomatopoeia, since it doesn't seem to derive “from a sound associated with what is named”, but from other word roots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Among most commons onomatopeias pertaining pets there are those diffused in language of and for children
>
> **bau** (dog's barking, woof),
>  **miao** (cat's meow),
>  **grrr** (sound of  growl, snarl), 
> **chicchirichì** (chicken's cock-a-doodle-doo)
>
> Among most common onomatopeias about things and actions there are:
>
> **tic tac**(clock),
>  **crac**(something breaks),
>  **plin** (tinkle),
>  **din don** (doorbell or bells in general),
>  **eccì** (achoo),
>  **brr** (used when one feels cold)
>
> They're often used in a replicated form
>
> **bau bau**,
>  **plin plin**,
>  **crac crac**
>
> or in only one syllable:
>
> **patapum** (wallop),
>  **taratatà**,
>  **patatrac** (a huge mess)
>
> Onomatopeias can also be used as substantive
>
> il **tic tac** della sveglia (clock's ticktoc),
>  i **chicchirichì** dei galli (chickens cock-a-doodle-doo),
>  un **patatrac**
>
> or produce verbs and substantives
>
> **miao** (meow)   ▶ miagolio / miagolare (to meow)
>
> **tic tac** (ticktoc)▶ ticchettio / ticchettare. (to tick)

Most of comics onomatopeias remain the same (although some of them may have been "italianized") and come from very common English verbs, such as:

**bang** (da to bang: esplodere)
**crash** (da to crash: rompersi)
**gulp** (da to gulp: inghiottire)
**sniff** (da to sniff: fiutare)
**splash** (da to splash: spruzzare)
**broooom** (da to broom: spazzare)
**boom** (da to boom: scoppiare, sometimes italianized in **bum**)
**slam** (da to slam: sbattere)
**sob** (da to sob: singhiozzare)
**chomp** , infine, deriva dall'omonimo verbo che significa "masticare rumorosamente".

You can find some references here:

[Treccani - onomatopee La grammatica Italiana](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/onomatopee_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)

[Treccani - onomatopea Enciclopedia dei ragazzi](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/onomatopea_%28Enciclopedia-dei-ragazzi%29/)